# switching Google accounts (apps(all free), etc)

Tags: accounts

I got my first smartphone, a Nexus 4, last year. I've been using two different Google accounts for e-mail etc, and I want to switch everything to one. I signed up for all my apps, etc on my nexus 4 using the Google account I want to get rid of. How do I switch over to just using my other gmail account on google play?

Comment: Sign into both accounts on your phone or tablet, download whatever apps you want from each account, then delete the old account, maybe they've blocked this since, but I've had this same problem, paid for apps, then got rid of the account and can't transfer the payment, so I signed into that account, downloaded the app, and then deleted the account, all is good...If I've misunderstood what you're asking I apologize, just let me know and I'll delete this and go away lol

Answer (score 1):

I just went through this with google and their answer is "you can't".  I knocked on several of their help chat doors (including the play store) and - sadly - got the same line there.